# Quick way to get different node values from a file in C#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I want to get the values of different nodes using different conditions of a xml file in different variables. Below is an example

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\MyFiles\test.xml", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
var a = (from x in doc.Descendants("title")
         select x).First().Value;
var b = (from y in doc.Descendants("label")  
         where y.Ancestors("sec").Any()
         select y).First().Value;
var c = (from z in doc.Descendants("sec").Attributes("id")
         select z).First().Value;
```

Can I do this in one line of code or maybe in a less redundant way?

Comment: Like this: [query linq to xml using xpath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-query-linq-to-xml-using-xpath) ?

Comment: See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-for-xpath-users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you certainly don't need to use the query expressions - they're mostly just getting in the way. This code would be simpler as:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\MyFiles\test.xml",LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
var a = doc.Descendants("title").First().Value;
var b = doc.Descendants("label").First(y => y.Ancestors("sec").Any()).Value;
var c = doc.Descendants("sec").Attributes("id").First().Value;
```

Alternatively, you could use XPath if you wanted. (`XPathSelectElements`, `XPathEvaluateNode` etc.) Personally I prefer to keep to using the query methods provided by LINQ to XML though.

Comment: Is that just a matter of (personal) preference or do you happen to know any drawbacks in using XPath?

Comment: @Fildor: I generally dislike embedding one language within another in the form of a string - it's generally more error-prone in my experience. I do it when I have to, but prefer options which can stay strongly typed, for example preferring LINQ over raw SQL.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @JonSkeet is it possible to use query expressions to get the values of the variables a,b,c in a single LINQ query? Using your above posted method is fine but I was just wondering if its possible get all of those in a single query...

Comment: @Don_B: It's doing three different queries, so I can't really imagine what that would look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous type too:

```
var res = from xml in xDoc.Descendants("filePath")
          select new
          {
              Title = xml.Descendants("title").FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
              Label = xml.Descendants("label").FirstOrDefault(l => l.Ancestors("sec").Any())?.Value,
              Sec = xml.Descendants("sec").Attributes("id").FirstOrDefault()?.Value
          };
```